# Sails JS graceful-fs error

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Just started trying to use Sails JS. Installed and created a test app and when I execute `sails lift` - I get:

```
error: Grunt :: (node:6108) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not suppo
rted. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent
 version.
```

I ran `npm update graceful-fs` but it didn't seem to do anything. Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there are issues with node 6.x. Downgraded to node 5.11.1 and it's working now.